# Passing data from one class to another in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to pass an output to a text area.

I have `Class Search` which handles all the searching and display the output using `System.out.println()`.

I have created `Class GUI` in order to make the console output `(System.out.println())` appear in the `JTextArea`.

I am trying to pass that data into the text area using objects but I dont know why it is not working.

`Class Search` has this method that calculates the output:

```
 public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException
```

`Class GUI` has the `text1`

In Class GUI I have tried this:

```
text1.setText(Search.searchIndex(searchString));
```

but it is giving me an error `searchString cannot be resolved to a variable`

Any suggestions ?

Regards.

Comment: Yes; start with the Java Tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

The method is not returning:

```
public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
```

Need to change `void` to `String` and also return the result:

```
public static String searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
    //do search
    return resultString; 
}
```

For the following to work:

```
text1.setText(Search.searchIndex(searchString));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this as well. Still showing the same error.

Comment: @HumamShbib: You need to post the code for the `Search` class.

Comment: here is the demo I am using http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/search/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files/LuceneDemo.java

Answer (score 0):

> searchString cannot be resolved to a variable

The above error is caused by the fact that you are trying to use the variable "searchString" without declaring it.

```
String searchString = "Some string that is in the search index";
text1.setText(Search.searchIndex(searchString));
```